# How to move and center a Sprite with Another Sprite in Unity”

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball and when it collide with another sprite, say a circle, i want ball to be centred inside the sprite and be static and all the ball's velocity should be transferred to the sprite and then sprite should start moving with the same transferred velocity.
I am trying my best and so far. With the code provided below, ball is striking the sprite but ball doesnt seem to be in center of the sprite and stay on its place where collision happened. There isnt any parent child relation between sprite and egg. Any help would be appreciated.

P.S => Link to the the problem video : https://imgur.com/a/yeHw6Vi

```
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 eggVelocity;
    private Rigidbody2D eggRigidBody;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        rb.gravityScale = 0;
    }


    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Egg"))
        {
            eggRigidBody = collision.rigidbody;
            eggVelocity = collision.rigidbody.velocity;
            eggRigidBody.transform.position = transform.position;
            eggRigidBody.bodyType = RigidbodyType2D.Static;
            rb.gravityScale = 1.0f;
            rb.velocity = eggVelocity;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you set your "egg" object to be static at a certain position which is exactly what happens in your video.

Further you don't disable it's collider so it pushes this object away at a certain angle.

You probably will want to

- disable the eggs collider so it doesn't participate in physics anymore and is rather just a visual
- and either parent it to this object or use a [FixedJoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-FixedJoint.html)

Comment: Removing static & using FixedJoint did the trick.